# How to call socket.io custom server event?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am learning socket.io and trying to create my chat. I have created a custom server event like this:

```
io.sockets.on("session:reload",function(sid){

var clients = io.sockets.clients();
console.log("123456");
clients.forEach(function(client){
    if(client.socket.session.id != sid) return;
    loadSession(sid,function(err,session){
        if(err){
            client.emit("error","server error");
            client.disconnect();
            return;
        }

        if(!session){
            client.emit("error","handshake unauth");
            client.disconnect();
            return;
        }
        client.socket.session = session;
    });
});
});
```

How can I call this from the server side?

```
io.sokets.$emit("session:reload",sid);
```

dosnt work in the new version of socket.io.

Comment: @mmm i realy dont now , u can check this in video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6rQbwgXXxEQ&index=14&list=PLypd1VrGv7FNghd_Fwldl19iJBaa4S2W5

Comment: I didnot find `io.sokets.$emit(` from socke.io doc, it is `io.sokets.emit(` without `$` per [doc](http://socket.io/docs/).

Comment: @zangw about emit i know , dont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

this is function on soket.js

```
io.on("sessreload",function(sid){
//some code
});
```

this is call this function

```
io.sockets._events.sessreload(sid);
```